# Proving $30x + 3y^2 + \frac{2z^3}{9} + 36 (\frac{1}{xy} + \frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{zx}) \ge 84$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $x, y, z$ are positive real numbers, prove that $$30x + 3y^2 + \frac{2z^3}{9} + 36 \left(\frac{1}{xy} + \frac{1}{yz} + \frac{1}{zx}\right) \ge 84.$$

I genuinely have no clue on how to proceed. Is it proved using repeated CS?

Comment: You're looking for a solution $(x,y,z)$ I assume? Presumably with a least one variable free? And given teh number theory tage, presumably you want integer solutions?

Comment: Uh, no. This is proving an inequality with 3 unknown variables.

Comment: I guess, you can interpret the problem as constrained minimization problem in the domain of $\mathbb{R}^3_{>0}$. After that, finding the local minimum, you’d probably come to it being $84$.

Comment: Oh... you want to solve the entire equality? Huh. Um. Yeah, that's gonna be really messy.

Comment: Yeah, it'd be messy for sure. Add that to the fact that I'm incompetent at 3 variables inequalities....

Comment: As I have already speculated above, it seems like a local minimum of the LHS function under the specified domain is exactly $84$, according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=min%7B30x%2B3y%5E2%2B2z%5E3%2F9%2B%2036%281%2Fxz%20%2B%201%2Fyx%20%2B%201%2Fyz%29%7D%20subject%20to%20%7Bx%20%3E0%2C%20y%20%3E0%2C%20z%20%3E0%7D). Probably, one can try solving it using Lagrange method

Comment: Plot the 3-D curve for all real numbers, noting that the inequality is true,  that is, f(x,y,z) > 84, at least in the first quadrant where x > 0, y > 0 and z >0.

Comment: @EthanLang I found three users voted to close your question. Perhaps you need to add some information e.g. source, your attempt, context, etc.

Comment: This needs some context (ref. above comment). It sounds like a really good question. Personally : given it's a contest question , all you will need to do is mention the textbook/PDF etc. where you found this, and one reference that you've been using to read up three-variable inequalities. If I may suggest one : I think Zdravko Cvetkovski's "Inequalities" contains some identities that may be useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Remark*: Once we know the equality case $x = 1, y = 2, z = 3$, we apply AM-GM.

Using AM-GM, we have
\begin{align*}
 &30\cdot x + 12 \cdot (y/2)^2
 + 6\cdot (z/3)^3 + 18 \cdot \frac{1}{xy/2} +  6\cdot \frac{1}{yz/6} + 12 \cdot \frac{1}{zx/3}\\
 \ge\,& 84\sqrt[84]{x^{30}\cdot (y/2)^{24}\cdot (z/3)^{18} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{xy/2}\right)^{18}\left(\frac{1}{yz/6}\right)^6\left(\frac{1}{zx/3}\right)^{12} }\\
 =\,& 84.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Comment: Not OP, but can you elaborate on how you figured out you could rearrange terms in that manner and then apply AM-GM twice after rearranging to get the desired result? It just seems kind of arbitrary, because the $-yz + 2/9 z^3 + 3y^2 - 84$ is a little too awkward to ignore, yet you proceed with AM-GM regardless. So I am just looking for any motivation or patterns you can share.

Comment: @politeproofs I added some explanation.

Comment: @politeproofs I just found it is just AM-GM directly.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

If we want to find the minimum, I think we can create a system from the implicit derivatives. We can multiply through by $xyz$, then subtract the right side to get:

$$f(x,y,z) = 30x^2yz+3xy^3z+\textstyle{\frac29}xyz^4+36x+36y+36z-84xyz \geqslant 0$$

And we want to show that this function has a minimum of $0$. Then we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 60xyz+3y^3z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}yz^4-84yz+36 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 30x^2z+9xy^2z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}xz^4 -84xz+36\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} &= 30x^2y+3xy^3+ \textstyle{\frac{8}{9}}xyz^3-84xy+36
\end{align}
$$

To find minima, we want all of these partial derivatives to be equal to $0$. This is a system of three equations in three variables:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
60xyz+3y^3z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}yz^4-84yz &= -36 \\ 
30x^2z+9xy^2z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}xz^4 -84xz &= -36 \\ 
30x^2y+3xy^3+ \textstyle{\frac{8}{9}}xyz^3-84xy &= -36 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

That's a bit... ugly. Let's try something:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
60x^2yz+3xy^3z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}xyz^4-84xyz +36x &= 0 \\ 
30x^2yz+9xy^3z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}xyz^4-84xyz +36y &= 0 \\ 
30x^2yz+3xy^3z+ \textstyle{\frac{8}{9}}xyz^4-84xyz +36z &= 0 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Now set $xyz=a$ and we have:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
60ax+3ay^2z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}az^3 +36x &= 84a \\ 
30ax+9ay^2z+ \textstyle{\frac{2}{9}}az^3 +36y &= 84a \\ 
30ax+3ay^2z+ \textstyle{\frac{8}{9}}az^3 +36z &= 84a 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

I do believe we'll need to solve the system by substitution. I'll leave this here for the moment and return.